# Javascript - Regex Does not contain some character

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to regex for not contain some character.

I need to show /%7(.*?);/g which dose not contain "=".

I try to input
    ?!xx=1
and change to
    ?!( (.*?)=(.*?) )
But it dose not work.

Please help. Thanks.

```
//Here is my simple regex
reg = /%7((?!xx=1).*?);/g ;

//Here is my string
str = "%7aa; %7bb=11; %7cc=123; %7xx=1; %7yy; %7zz=2;"

//I need
%7aa; and %7yy;
```

Comment: Try `/%7(?:(?!xx=1).)*?;/g` or `/%7(?:(?!xx=1)[^;])*;/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a negative lookahead, try using a `^` block:

```
const reg = /%7([^=;]+);/g;
```

The `([^=;]+)` bit matches any non-`=`, the condition you're looking for, and non-`;`, the character at the end of your regex.

I left the capture group in since your question's regex also contains it.

```js
const reg = /%7([^=;]+);/g;
const str = "%7aa; %7bb=11; %7cc=123; %7xx=1; %7yy; %7zz=2;"

const matches = str.match(reg);
console.log(matches);
```